# Change the UIImage of a UIButton when other UIButton is clicked

Tags: iphone

When a user clicks `UIButton1(rewind button)` requirement is to change the `UIImage` of other `UIButton2(playbutton)`. How can i do that.

```
UIButton *rewindButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[rewindButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rewind:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
rewindButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 38, 38);
UIImage *imge = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rewind Icon .png"];
[rewindButton setImage:imge forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *rewind = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rewindButton];

-(void)rewind:(id)sender{
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
[timer invalidate];
ContainerViewController *viewController = [[[ContainerViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}

//Add Play Button

_playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
_playButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 38, 38);
[_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"52.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.playButton];


-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
 if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];

}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];
   if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                            target:self
                                            selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    }
    } 
    }
```

When a user clicks `UIButton1(rewind button)` requirement is to change the `UIImage` of other `UIButton2(play button)`from play icon.png to pauseicon.png.

How can i do that.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does setting the button's image directly not work?

```
-(void)rewind:(id)sender{
    [_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //...
}
```

Comment: How can i have play button do these steps [audioPlayer play];
        [self resumeTimer];
        [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer]; when rewind button changes the UIImage of play button [_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; it means that when rewind button changes the uiimage of play button to pause and when user tries to pause it and when user resumes it then play button should do these steps [audioPlayer play];
        [self resumeTimer];
        [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];

Comment: The _playButton is already connected to your playpauseAction: method which performs those steps. Instead of just setting the play buttons image in rewind: you could try -(void)rewind: {[audioPlayer pause]; audioPlayer.currentTime = 0; [self playpauseAction:_playButton]; //... }